# Формат аудио для android приложения

Tags: android, аудио

делаю приложение типа детские песни. сейчас приложение содержит 95 треков в mp3. битрейт которых я уменьшил до 64кб/с. После создания apk весит 130мб что довольно немало на мой вгзляд. Хотел бы узнать в каком формате лучше всего хранить аудио? и какой битрейт можно выставить чтобы уменьшить размер apk?

P.S. не предлагайте пожалуйста хранить аудио на сервере.. приложение будет работать офф.

Answer (score 1):

> битрейт которых я уменьшил до 64кб/с

При таком битрейте аудио будет звучать объективно плохо.

> Хотел бы узнать в каком формате лучше всего хранить аудио?

Подобного рода аудио я бы хранил именно в MP3 – он обеспечивает хорошее соотношение между качеством, размером файла и совместимостью.

Как вариант, можете попробовать AAC, с *примерно* таким же качеством, аудио будет весить чуть меньше, однако в этом случае возможны проблемы с совместимостью.

> и какой битрейт можно выставить чтобы уменьшить размер apk?

Очевидно, что уменьшение битрейта влечет за собой уменьшение размера файла, однако чем меньше битрейт – тем хуже качество.

> P.S. не предлагайте пожалуйста хранить аудио на сервере.. приложение будет работать офф.

Если Вы хотите уменьшить непосредственно размер APK, то можно не включать в него аудио, однако при первом старте приложения предлагать пользователю отдельно загрузить какие-либо пакеты композиций. После загрузки их можно будет использовать без интернета.

PS. Я не специалист в сфере цифровой обработки сигналов, поэтому, возможно, кто-нибудь предложит более объективно качественный ответ.